# tmux doesn't resize with terminal window

Tags: terminal, tmux

When I resize a terminal window containing a tmux session, tmux doesn't detect this change, but continues to function normally within the old window boundaries.  `tmux ls` shows no other attached clients before I attach:

```
$ tmux ls
admin: 1 windows (created Mon Apr 27 15:12:58 2015) [272x75]
apt-runs: 3 windows (created Mon Apr 27 15:17:50 2015) [272x75]
lal-dev: 4 windows (created Tue Jun  9 12:24:25 2015) [238x73]
```

This only happens with a particular host (running tmux 1.9a), and detaching/reattaching fixes the issue (until the window is resized again).  What might be causing this?

Before resize:
[image: Before]

After resize:
[image]

Comment: Is there another terminal window attached to that session that limits the size?

Comment: @Anthon Nope – `tmux ls` shows no other clients. I've clarified this in the question.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue; Noteworthy is that we're both on OSX although I'm probably running a more up-to-date version. Have you found any fix, seeing as there is no accepted answer?

Comment: I'm still seeing this in 2020.  Issuing `resize` in the shell running in tmux resolves the problem, until the terminal window is resized again.  This is slightly different from what @saterHater said below.  He seemed to suggest that you need to detach tmux before issuing this command.

Comment: This issue seems relevant: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/359.  Also, I should point out that I am running xmonad, which is perhaps as unfamiliar a window manager to tmux as MacOS is.

Answer (score 20):

The easiest thing to do is to detach any other clients from the sessions when you attach:

```
tmux attach -d
```

or short

```
tmux a -d
```

Alternately, you can move any other clients to a different session before attaching to the session: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7819465/1069083

Comment: Like I said in the question, there were no other clients.  Unlike this case, when there are multiple clients with different terminal sizes, the status bar remains at the bottom of the screen, and the unused area is filled in with dots.  I never solved this problem, but I no longer work on the system where it occurred.

Answer (score 20):

This can happen when tmux's `window-size` option is set to `manual`. To unset the option, you can press Ctrl+B and type

```
:set-option -u window-size
```

`window-size` is a per-window option, so you will have to run for every mis-sized window in your session.

From tmux's man page:

> **window-size** `largest` | `smallest` | `manual` | `latest`: Configure how tmux determines the window size. If set to `largest`, the size of the largest attached session is used; if `smallest`, the size of the smallest. If `manual`, the size of a new window is set from the **default-size** option and windows are resized automatically. With `latest`, uses the size of the client that had the most recent activity. See also the **resize-window** command and the **aggressive-resize** option.

The default is `latest` as of tmux 3.2 (released Feb 3rd, 2020), or `smallest` on earlier versions, where `latest` didn't exist. Notably, however, **using iTerm2 with tmux [Control Mode](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Control-Mode) will set it to `manual` without asking you**, and that setting will stick around even after detaching iTerm2 and connecting in non-Control Mode with a different client. Other terminal emulators supporting Control Mode likely behave the same way, but I've only tested iTerm2.

Comment: This should be the answer. Unsetting the `window-size` option worked for me. Which makes sense; if `tmux` gets into the state where it won't resize to the terminal window, and no other session is attached, it's because it's `window-size` is set to `manual`.

Comment: I tried this solution (when my tmux window didn't resize after detaching and reattaching from a larger terminal).  When I used the ":" command to run "set-option", my tmux window resized itself when presenting the ":" bar at the bottom.  Go figure.

Comment: One-liner to apply this fix to all windows in the current session: `tmux list-windows -F '#{window_id}' | while read w; do tmux set-option -u -t $w window-size; done`

Answer (score 9):

I'm not well-versed in terminal lingo, but I managed to get-rid of this bug by doing the following steps:

1. leave the session by pressting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>  <kbd>d</kbd> (don't worry, you can return to the session completely intact)
2. Check if your console application is running `xterm`. If `echo $TERM` returns `xterm` then this procedure might work for you.
3. type `resize` into your terminal.
4. return to your session by re-invoking `tmux`. As you can see, all of your sessions are running like you never left tmux at all.

Tmux links it's terminal size with your `xterm` 'size' variable. If you happen to have your `$TERM` set to `screen`, then I can't help you, since I don't know what the commands are for that TERM session.

Comment: Going that route, you'll have to do this each time you resize the window.  That's exactly what OP stated they did, in the question.

Comment: **Invoking `resize`** (after `apt install xterm`) was the crucial step I was missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked for me! By the way, is it possible to automize the process? _i.e._, let `tmux` automatically read the terminal size and update it?